Descartes Statement in Second Meditation is illogical?
In the second paragraph of Meditation Two: Concerning the Nature of the Human Mind: That it is better known than the Body, Descartes writes
“Therefore I suppose that everything I see is false. I believe that none of what my deceitful memory represents ever existed .”
Surely when anyone, including Descartes, is writing about the non existence of something, in this case ‘all which his deceitful memory represents’ they are admitting that it exists in some capacity. This is the classic paradox of non-being.
So therefore, I am keen to interpret his statement as meaning ‘I will now believe that none of what my deceitful memory represents ever existed in a real corporeal realm, but was all and always just an image of my mind.”
Is this a correct interpretation or am I missing something?

No, when you say that something doesn't exist, you aren't admitting that it exists in some capacity

"I will now believe that none of what my deceitful memory represents ever existed in a real corporeal realm, but was all and always just an image of my mind” is way too loaded with naive presuppositions that Descartes intends to question and scrutinize. The whole point of methodological doubt is to suspend such habitual preconceptions as "real corporeal realm" and "my mind". He wipes all of it clean, not just crosses out some specific boxes.

@DavidGudeman How so? “X does not exist.” You just described X in the proposition so you admit that it does exist in some capacity. For example ‘Unicorns don’t exist.’ entails that you have some conception of a Unicorn in your mind, but that you are saying it doesn’t exist in reality.

@Conifold Ok I see. But still my question remains, how could he say that it never existed, and wipe it all clean, when he is still referring to it using language and so therefore has an idea of what it is. I guess I am confused as to what he is meaning when he says that he will now believe that ‘it never existed’.

@Conifold I think the key word in Descartes’ statement is ‘represents’. I think upon further inspection, it is clear that he is making a distinction between the realm of physical reality and the realm of imagination, for he is denying that the images in his mind, ‘what his deceitful memory represents’ ever existed (in reality).

There is a difference between truth and meaning. He wipes it all clean concerning the truth of it, but language with its meanings is still available to him, providing options beyond "corporeal realm" and "my mind". What his memory represents to him need not be "physical reality" or anything else specific, whatever it is is dismissed for the purpose, just as "him" need not be the loaded idea of "mind".  Of course, that he could truly control his beliefs this way is highly questionable in hindsight, and critics charged that he, in fact, did not, but at least this was the aspiration.

The concept of a unicorn exists. That doesn't mean the unicorn itself exists.

@DavidGudeman "unicorn" exists in the dictionary. Even staunch atheists who argue theists would not dispute that "God" exists in the dictionary; or even exists in the mind/imagination of theists. He/she/it just doesn't exist in the atheists imagination of objective reality. IOW reality, existence has many shades

"God" is not God. God is a supernatural being. "God" is a word. They have nothing in common. You are failing to make simple and fundamental distinctions between references and the things referenced. This is sophistry, not philosophy.

Maybe you should familiarize yourself with St. Anselm @DavidGudeman??

The Ontological argument doesn't confuse reference and thing referenced.

@DavidGudeman It very much does. That’s the whole problem with it.

@MattHarper, the Ontological Argument is ontological, not linguistic.

You are on the right track in my view — Descartes is made too much of in western philosophy.
Methodological doubt is all very well on the face of it, but Descartes never really gets out of his mind.
Below I give some of the notable philosophers who have criticized Descartes' mind-addiction.
Existence exists(!!) in multiple senses because we exist and experience ourselves in multiple ways — sometimes (but not always) intellectually, sometimes physically, sometimes emotionally. And so on.  We are free to make abstractions out of these, but we then need to remember that 'to abstract' is synonymous with 'to extract' — something is left out!
Note:


It's only too easy to criticize a pioneer, forgetting that he had so little to fall back on; also I don't know Descartes personally — never met him. So below Descartes should be really heard as Cartesianism in its most vanilla form.  That's too long so Descartes will have to do!

We need add the vanilla-caveat because there may be nuances that have been forgotten. This is after all philosophy we are talking not historiography.

I feel this conspective criticism is long overdue because western philosophy, thence society, thence the rest of the world is suffering too much due overindulging the mind as though its super trustworthy.



David Hume
His criticisms are well known — he is sceptical of (Descartes') rationalism and suggests empiricism instead
Kant
Kant followed Hume in saying that while the mind is crucial it does not stand alone without sensory input
Gilbert Ryle
By coining the cute phrase 'Ghost in the machine' reminded us that as philosophers we always need to be chary of dualism
Wittgenstein
Descartes' introspective method and focus on private mental states misunderstood the nature of language and meaning, which are inherently public and social.
The last three are my favorites though I cannot claim to understand the first two very well
Heidegger
He suggests that Descartes inverts the fundamental nature of being in 'Cogito ergo sum'. We experience being always as 'Dasein' — being in the world — and not as isolated detached rational minds as Descartes imagined
Spinoza
Strong commitment to non dualism — There is one reality 'Substance' alone. We call it variously God or Nature. We know it personally as the two facets mind and body. But its a delusion to separate them
Merleau-Ponty
Perception and consciousness are fundamentally and always embodied experiences. The separation is a fiction. This has been carried into further detail more recently by George Lakoff

Althought not generally discussed in that context, Descartes has an occult side.
You can read more on this in the book Descartes:An Intellectual Biography.
A major part of his work is based on his dreams (altered state of consciousness) that he experienced.

One factor that must be borne in mind in considering the third dream
is that dreams were a standard literary device in which symbols could
be deployed in a way that would be anomalous in other contexts.
p108


The Meditationes read like an account of a spiritual journey in which
the truth is only to be discovered by a purging, followed by a kind of
rebirth.
p336

Without going into more details - as the book speak for itsel - I believe that Meditation Two describes a realization that is very close to maya in Hindu philosophy.

In Advaita Vedanta (Hindu) philosophy, maya is the
limited, purely physical and mental reality in which our everyday
consciousness has become entangled. Maya is believed to be an
illusion, a veiling of the true, unitary Self—the Cosmic Spirit also
known as Brahman.
compiled definition

